# Renaming files content with PowerShell leaves special characters

Tags: xml, powershell, rename, special-characters

I created the PowerShell script to rename some files content.

I noticed some special characters (������) appeared after the renaming.

I use the following script:

```
 $configFiles = Get-ChildItem -Include *.xml -rec
 $string = "AppointmentRequest"
 foreach ($file in $configFiles)
 {    $result = Select-String $file.PSPath -Pattern $string
      if ($result -ne $null) {
     (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
      Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "AppointmentRequest", "ShiftRequest" } |
     Set-Content  $file.PSPath}
 }
```

Comment: Use `-Encoding UTF8`, assuming you're using Windows PowerShell. *Special characters* like the one's you're seeing are because of encoding issues.

Comment: Thanks. Already tried. Didn't work

Comment: _Didn't work_ ... You can set the utf8 encoding on both `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` cmdlets

Comment: The issue could be the font that is being used doesn't support the characters.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).